# Using TAP to sniff or modify incoming eth packets

Tags: networking, ip, tun, iproute, tun-tap

I've tried https://github.com/TOGoS/TUN2UDP

This allows me to do:

```
Application --> TAP 
Read from TAP --> Write to UDP (under my control)
Read from UDP --> Write to TAP (under my control)
TAP --> Application
```

What I want to do is:

```
Application --> ETH
Read from ETH --> Write to TAP (under my control)
TAP --> Application
```

In other words I want to intercept incoming packets at layer 2 and have control to block them, modify them, or pass them through.

I think perhaps bridging ETH and the TAP is the key but I can't figure out how to access this bridge programmatically in the way I need.